# What is the effect of using float loadfactor to a HashSet?

Tags: java

Why float loadfactor affect to a HashSet? what is the significant of it?

Answer (score 7):

You need to read the explanation included in the JavaDoc for HashMap

> The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

An instance of `HashMap` has two parameters that affect its performance:

`initial capacity` and `load factor`.

The capacity is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the `initial capacity` is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created. The `load factor` is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.

As a general rule, the `default load factor` (.75) offers a good tradeoff between time and space costs. Higher values decrease the space overhead but increase the lookup cost (reflected in most of the operations of the HashMap class, including `get` and `put`). The expected number of entries in the map and its load factor should be taken into account when setting its initial capacity, so as to minimize the number of rehash operations. If the `initial capacity` is greater than the maximum number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash operations will ever occur.

i.e. if

**`load factor`** x **`capacity`**  >  **`number of entries`**

then Rehashing will never occur.

If many mappings are to be stored in a HashMap instance, creating it with a sufficiently large capacity will allow the mappings to be stored more efficiently than letting it perform automatic rehashing as needed to grow the table.